# Why is my newest css file not getting updated in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

Please forgive me if I'm not using the correct lingo when describing what I'm doing.  This is week 2 of me jumping into web design using html, css, and javascript.

What is the difference between clicking the reload button on my browser, and going to the address bar and pressing Enter to go to the webpage?

I made changes to my js and css files and clicked the reload button on my browser.  However when I go to inspect elements on the page in my browser to debug, the js and css files are old and doesn't have my updates.  Only when I go to the address bar and press Enter on the webpage does it show my new css file when I'm debugging.

To illustrate what I'm doing, someone gave me a trick in HTML so that when I make changes and the web service is restarted, it will(should) reload the files without me needing to do anything:

```
  <script src="/static/js/plan_runner.js?u={{ app_start }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/static/css/plan_runner.css?u={{ app_start }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have this snippet in my route.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
APP_START=int(time.time())
...
...
@app.route('/blah')
def tester():
...
...
return render_template("test.html', app_start=APP_START)
```

However, this seems to only work when I go to the address bar and click enter on my url.  When I'm on the page and click the "reload" button on my browser, it doesn't seem to update my js or css files.

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between the clicking the reload button and hitting Enter on the address bar and why one case updates my css and js files but the other case doesn't?  Thanks.

Comment: It's called caching. If you develop something on the web, usually you can just open developer console/web inspector (different browser - different name)... While it is opened caching will be turned off

Answer (score 0):

This happens with me many times and I found a solution for this issue.

Run the flask server in development (debug) mode. To do that just run these commands to start flask server:

```
 1. export FLASK_ENV=development
 2. export FLASK_APP=app.py (replace app.py with your main file name and .py)
 3. flask run
```

This will restart the server on every change you save.

2nd solution:
Disable browser cache. Google Chrome allows you to disable cache.

[image]